# Branches in TFS merged up appear as pending to merge down

Tags: .net, tfs, merge, branch, tfs-2015

I have the following structure on TFS:

```
MAIN
RELEASES
      \---
          VERSION 1
```

VERSION1 is a branch of MAIN, nothing fancy. We do a development on VERSION 1 and then merge it up to MAIN.

From time to time some of these merges appear as pending to merge down from MAIN to VERSION 1.

If we go to MAIN -> Merge, select VERSION 1 as destination and select "Merge selected changesets" we expected to see the check-ins done on MAIN and not present on VERSION 1 but for some reason we see some of the check-ins done on VERSION 1 and merged up to MAIN (of course they are present on VERSION 1 as it was the source branch where the development was not.

Any hints about why this is happening? We maintain several versions active at the same time and we really need to verify that all the merges to the relevant versions have been done.

If I do the merge down again I can see a modified file with the attributes [merge, edit] with no differences at all (so in fact there is no need to do the merge back again as it was expected).

**UPDATE**

In the following image you can see the merges done. 00.28.02 is like VERSION 1 and Source is like MAIN.

[image]

Anyway when I check the changesets pending to move from MAIN to VERSION 1 (00.28.02) it appears the changeset 42741 :S

[image]

Comment: Hi Ignacio Soler Garcia, any update on this issue, have you figured it out?

Comment: I hadn't the time yet to investigate on this  ... but I won't forget. What I'm sure is that we are not doing partial merges. We merge always complete change sets. Anyway I will followup with whatever I find.

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, seems issue is the changes merged previously  still in pending change when you merge from Main to version1.

Usually this kind of phenomenon stands for there are partially merged changeset. When use the Track Changeset feature and clicked the Visualize button to see if the change was merged. It will show that it was merged but has a different background color and an asterisk.

A **partial merge** is recorded when **only some changes from a changeset are merged into the target**. For your reference, there are two common scenarios in below which you can end up with partial merges (*use dev instead of version1*):

**Scenario 1:Undo some pending changes when you are checking the merged files**

In this case, even though we already merged changeset **Dev** to **Main**, it is still a merge candidate. This is caused by the fact that the merge engine detected that there are still some changes in that changeset which were not propagated from Dev to Main.

**Scenario 2: Performed the merge at feature level not from the top of the branch**

For example: consider that you have two branches **Main** and **Dev**, each of them has two folders (Feature1 and Feature2) and each feature folder contains one file. We edit both files from the feature folders (`Dev\Feature1\feature1.txt` and `Dev\Feature2\feature2.txt`) and check-in the changes.

If you perform the merge operation at the Feature1 level.（*Changset142→
 Changeset143*） You will notice in the Pending Changes window that only the edit done in the `Feature1` folder will be merged. Complete the merge.

If you take a look at the merge history of the Feature1 folder you will see that all changes from changeset 142 have been merged into changeset 143.

However,if you take a look at the merge history of Main you will see that only parts of changeset 142 have been merged into changeset 143. This is normal as changeset 142 has some changes – the edit of the file in the Feature2 folder – which were not delivered.

---

***In  your case*** to determine if it;s a partial merge, to figure out what changes have been merged and what changes from the changeset were left out. **The only way** to achieve this is to **diff** the contents of the changeset that was partially merged, and the contents of the changeset that was generated as the result of the merge. More detail info you can refer this blog: [Partial Merges in TFS – A Guide](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dstfs/2009/05/04/partial-merges-in-tfs-a-guide/)

If there are no files actually changed, you could use below solution to *make the  specific changeset no longer appear as a merge candidate*:

> You can do a [discard
>   merge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/merge-command).
>   This has to be done from the command line. Open up the [Developer
>   command
>   prompt](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229859%28v=vs.110%29.aspx),
>   then navigate to a folder under either of your branches (i.e. navigate
>   to one of the affected
>   [workspaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg490753%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)).
>   Then type:
>
> ```
> tf merge /r /discard "$/Project/B1" "$/Project/B2" /v:C12345~C12345
> ```
>
> This will take the changeset identified (in this case it was changeset
>   `#12345`), and update it as merged to the target branch (branch B2). The target files will be checked out, but they will not be changed - you
>   can simply check them in to complete the operation. After that the
>   changeset will no longer appear as a merge candidate. You can specify
>   a range of changesets to merge at the same time, but they should be
>   contiguous.
>
> Note that after doing this a changeset will occasionally still show up
>   as a merge candidate - this is rather uncommon with the latest
>   versions of TFS, and it is virtually impossible to fix (unless you are
>   running your own local install of TFS and want to get your hands very
>   dirty in the database). If you end up with one of these marooned
>   changesets, just ignore it.
>
> Source:
>   [Finding merge candidates in TFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37521815/finding-merge-candidates-in-tfs)