# Ignoring 2 changesets

Tags: tfs

I'm using TFS 2010. I have 2 changesets in child branch that I do not want to merge in the parent branch.

e.g

1. (1002) Rolled back changeset
2. (1001) Changeset checked in by mistake

I don't want these changesets from appearing in the merge menu when you attempt to merge into the parent branch.

If I have understood correctly that I can use the following TFS command to ignore these 2 particular changesets or will the rollback changeset interfere?

```
tf merge childbranch parentbranch  /r /version:1001~1002 /discard
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can do a [discard
>   merge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/merge-command?view=vsts).
>   This has to be done from the command line. Open up the [Developer
>   command
>   prompt](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229859%28v=vs.110%29.aspx),
>   then navigate to a folder under either of your branches (i.e. navigate
>   to one of the affected
>   [workspaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg490753%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)).
>   Then type:
>
> ```
> tf merge /r /discard "$/Project/B1" "$/Project/B2" /v:C12345~C12345
> ```
>
> This will take the changeset identified (in this case it was changeset
>   `#12345`), and update it as merged to the target branch (branch B2). The target files will be checked out, but they will not be changed - you
>   can simply check them in to complete the operation. After that the
>   changeset will no longer appear as a merge candidate. You can specify
>   a range of changesets to merge at the same time, but they **should be
>   contiguous**.
>
> Note that after doing this a changeset will occasionally still show up
>   as a merge candidate - this is rather uncommon with the latest
>   versions of TFS, and it is virtually impossible to fix (unless you are
>   running your own local install of TFS and want to get your hands very
>   dirty in the database). If you end up with one of these marooned
>   changesets, just ignore it.
>
> Source:
>   [Finding merge candidates in TFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37521815/finding-merge-candidates-in-tfs)

***Note:*** When the command has finished, you still need to check in the merge.

For more tutorials, you could also refer below blogs:

- [TFS: Discard changesets when merging to branches](http://blog.vicreative.nl/2016/01/tfs-discard-changesets-when-merging-to-branches/)
- [DISCARDING CHANGESETS IN TFS](https://simonlearningsqlserver.wordpress.com/2013/06/17/discarding-changesets-in-tfs/)